# How to add rows to TableView without having any data model

Tags: javafx-8

I'm fairly new to javafx, so please bear with me if my question is unclear. I've a TableView which need to be populated using an ObservableList.

The code below populates my "data" with the arraylists generated out of the Map, which in turn is used to add rows to my table.

```
TableView<ArrayList> table = new TableView<>();

ObservableList<ArrayList> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

     for(int i=0;i<listSelectedVerticesIds.size();i++){
          ArrayList<String> tempString = new ArrayList<>();
                for(Map.Entry<String,String> temp2 : mapVertex.get(listSelectedVerticesIds.get(i)).entrySet()){
                    tempString.add(temp2.getValue());
                }
                data.add(tempString);           
            }
    table.setItems(data);
```

However, I do not see the table populated with the list in "data". I'm guessing this is because there is no data binding (using setCellValueFactory). However, as you can see I dont have a data model class. All of my data comes from the Map as strings which I would like to populate in my tableview.

Please suggest.

Comment: I am assuming from this code that one row of data is represented by the arraylist in the observablelist? Meaning your table view would be something like this: TableView<ObservableList<String>> is that correct?

Comment: Yes, one row of data is an ArrayList. Basically, in the code, tempString has the values for one row of data. I'm adding multiple tempString ArrayList to "data", for multiple rows.

Comment: Can you post your table columns and their cell value factories?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it that works great.  You don't need a data structure to populate a table.  You only see that because that's what most examples show. It is an extremely common use case to populate a table from a database or a file.  I don't understand why this is so hard to find examples for.  Well, hope this helps.

```
private TableView<ObservableList<StringProperty>> table = new TableView<>();
private ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

private void updateTableRow() {
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++) {
        ObservableList<StringProperty> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
            data.add(column, new SimpleStringProperty(myList.get(row + (column * numberOfRows))));
        }
        table.getItems().add(data);
    }
}
```